# Python asyncio Await Tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Need: Python 3.7 or later.

Two functions `main1` and `main2` defined below. One create tasks and then await all of them at the end; Another create and await each at a time.

While `main1` take 2 seconds and `main2` takes 30 seconds. Why?

```
import asyncio

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main1():
    tasks = []
    for _ in range(10):
        task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'hello'))
        task2 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'world'))
        tasks.append(task1)
        tasks.append(task2)
    for x in tasks:
        await x

async def main2():
    for _ in range(10):
        await asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'hello'))
        await asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'world'))

asyncio.run(main2())
```

**EDIT 1:**

Here is a `main3` version, which take 20 seconds. I'd say the whole thing is just out of intuition :(

```
async def main3():
    for _ in range(10):
        task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'hello'))
        task2 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'world'))
        await task1
        await task2
```

**EDIT 2:**

(With some more sample code added below) I've read detailed answers from @freakish, I still stuck at one point: So only continuous `await` will *corporately* work in parallel (main4)?

Since `create_task()` takes no time (right?), why not both two `await` in `main5` run in background so that `main5` would took max time of (task1, task2)?

Is this `await` mechanism by design, or just a `asyncio` limitation (in design or in implementation)?

And any `await` detailed behaviors defined in official Python docs?

```
# took 2 seconds
async def main4():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'hello'))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'world'))
    await task1
    await task2

# took 3 seconds
async def main5():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'hello'))
    await task1
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'world'))
    await task2
```

Comment: `why not both two await in main5 run in background` They do. Its just `task2` does not exist until task1 finishes. Because there's `await task1` before `task2 = create_task(...)`. The `await` directive (unlike create_task) stops code from advancing until the task is finished.

Comment: @freakish So there isn't a god thing inside asyncio "foresee" all tasks in a coroutine and make them work together? Could I say asyncio is not smart enough (i.e. why task2 to be created (in main5) has to wait the first `await` done, it's a-wait anyway)

Comment: Asyncio is not an oracle, you're right. But not smart enough? Is a hammer not smart? It's a tool, it depends on how you use it. As you've seen in my answer you can create many **non-equivalent** flows. There is no better/worse flow. Each one of them has pros and cons, can be useful, it depends on what you are trying to achieve. At the end of the day only the programmer knows where he wants to await. No compiler/interpreter can make that decision for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `main1` creates **all** tasks at the same time and then awaits **all** of them after they are created. Everything happens in parallel. And so total time is **maximum** of all times which is 2s.

While `main2` creates a new task only **after** previous one finishes. Everything happens sequentially. So total time is **sum** of all times which (judging from code) should be 30s.

**Edit:** say you have 3 tasks: `task1, task2, task3`. If you do

1. create task1
2. await task1
3. create task2
4. await task2
5. create task3
6. await task3

then the total execution time is obviously `task1.time + task2.time + task3.time` because there is no background processing. The flow is sequential. Now lets say you do

1. create task1
2. create task2
3. create task3
4. await task1
5. await task2
6. await task3

Now `task1, task2, task3` **run in background**. So it takes `T1 = task1.time` to process 4. But at pt 5 it takes `T2 = max(task2.time - T1, 0)` to process it beceause it already worked in background for `T1` time. At pt 6 it takes `T3 = max(task3.time - T2 - T1, 0)` to process it because it already worked in background for `T1+T2` time. Now some maths is required to calculate that the sum of `T1+T2+T3=max(task1.time, task2.time, task3.time)`.

But the intuition is this: if `taskX` was the longest one and it finished then everything else finished due to parallel processing. So `await` returns immediatly making the total processing time maximum of all times.

**Side note:** there are nuanses: this only works when you actually do parallelizable stuff like `asyncio.sleep()`. If those tasks are synchronous (say some cpu calculations) then both cases will give 30s.

**Edit2:** So your `main3` has a bit different flow. It lets two tasks to run in parallel. But no more:

1. create task1
2. create task2
3. await task1
4. await task2
5. create task3
6. create task4
7. await task3
8. await task4

So this time `task1` and `task2` happen in parallel. But only after they are done, `task3` and `task4` can run. In parallel. So for each group the total time is maximum but you have to sum separate groups. I.e. the total execution time is `max(task1.time, task2.time)+max(task3.time, task4.time)` which in your case is

```
max(1,2) + ... + max(1,2) [10 times] = 20
```

Comment: I would expect answers like this. But the result is just not intuitive. Can you put more details here?

Comment: @mitnk I also added comment for `main3`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I added a "Edit 2" section in question :)